# How to remove index from form list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of report observations in flutter for a ListView.separated widget

```
Map _report = {
  'observations': <Observation>[
   const Observation(observation: ''),
 ]
};
```

I added a function to add new observations to the list. That works well. But when I try to remove an observation from the list, instead of removing the observation from the selected index form I always removes the last observation on the list.

This is my full code

```
class AddReportScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddReportScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const routeName = '/add-report';

  @override
  State<AddReportScreen> createState() => _AddReportScreenState();
}

class _AddReportScreenState extends State<AddReportScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Map _report = {
    'observations': <Observation>[
      const Observation(observation: ''),
    ]
  };


// Add a new observation to the list
  void _addNewObservation() {
    setState(() {
      _report['observations'].add(Observation(observation: ''));
    });
  }


// REset the form
  void _resetForm() {
    setState(() {
      _formKey.currentState!.reset();
      _report = {
        'observations': <Observation>[
          const Observation(observation: ''),
        ]
      };
    });
  }


// Remove observation function
  void _removeObservation(int index) {
    setState(() {
      final obs = _report['observations'];
      obs.removeAt(index);
      _report['observations'] = obs;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Add Report'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            // Submit the form
            print('Valid');
            print([
              for (var observation in _report['observations'])
                '${observation.observation}'
            ]);
            _resetForm();
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: ListView.separated(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return Row(
                    key: Key(index.toString()),
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 4,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            _report['observations'][index] =
                                Observation(observation: value);
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Observation ${index + 1}",
                          ),
                          validator: (String? value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Required field.';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      if (_report['observations'].length > 1)
                        Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Remove the observation
                            _removeObservation(index);
                          },
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(
                                const CircleBorder()),
                          ),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                        ))
                    ],
                  );
                },
                itemCount: _report['observations'].length,
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) =>
                    const Divider(),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _addNewObservation();
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(
                  const Size(
                    double.infinity,
                    50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Text('Add Observation'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            const ElevatedButton(onPressed: null, child: Text("Add Images")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I print the list of observations after removal, it shows that the selected observation was removed from the list. But when flutter sets state it removes the last observation from the list.

Comment: If you are using getx, can you include that tag as well

Comment: No I'm not @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Can include more about `Observation`

Comment: `
class Observation {
  Observation({required this.observation});

  String observation;
  final String uniqueId = const Uuid().v4();
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your item's key in the itemBuilder should be connected somehow with your observation object and not index

Try changing:

```
key: Key(index.toString()),
```

to something like:

```
key: Key(_report['observations'][index].id),
```

More info about keys in Flutter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: When i do that it removes the observation along with other following observations

**key: Key(_report['observations'][index].uniqueId)**